# Using random.uniform gives "only size-1 arrays ... "error

Tags: python, arrays, random

I wrote the following code to use these random numbers in the calculation. Running the code gives an error.

```
import numpy as np
from math import *
from scipy.integrate import quad

sig=10
for i in range (1,10):
    R1=np.random.uniform(0,1,i)
    R2=np.random.uniform(0,1,i)
    def delta():
        d=sig*(sqrt(-2*log(R1))*cos(radians(R2)))
        return d
    print(delta())
```

it Gives this error:

`d=sig*(sqrt(-2*log(R1))*cos(radians(R2)))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
d = sig * (sqrt(-2 * log(R1)) * cos(radians(R2)))
```

to

```
d = sig * (np.sqrt(-2 * np.log(R1)) * np.cos(np.radians(R2)))
```

---

The NumPy functions, `np.sqrt`, `np.log`, `np.cos`, `np.radians` can be applied to NumPy arrays. The `math` functions imported with `from math import *` can only be applied to scalars or arrays of size 1.